# How to filter this database

Tags: sql-server

This is the data that current I have.

[image]

But I want to filter it as this bottom one.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`select * from table_name order by Column_name`

or else

```
select Convert(Date,ColumnName) from table_name order by Column_name`
```

SQL Server provides a number of options you can use to format a date/time string. One of the first considerations is the actual date/time needed. The most common is the current date/time using getdate(). This provides the current date and time according to the server providing the date and time. If a universal date/time is needed, then getutcdate() should be used. To change the format of the date, you convert the requested date to a string and specify the format number corresponding to the format needed.

1. Use the date format option along with CONVERT function
2. To get YYYY-MM-DD to use SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 23)
3. To get MM/DD/YYYY use SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1)
4. Check out the chart to get a list of all format options

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT d.ID,d.[Date],MIN(d.[Time]) AS [Time-in],MAX(d.[Time]) AS [Time-out]
    ,CASE WHEN MAX(d.[Time]) > '17:00:00' THEN CONVERT(TIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,MAX(d.[Time])) - CONVERT(DATETIME,'17:00:00')) ELSE NULL END AS [OT]
FROM (
    SELECT t.ID
        ,CONVERT(DATE,t.[Date]) AS [Date]
        ,CONVERT(TIME,t.[Date]) AS [Time]
    FROM [YourTableName] t
) d
GROUP BY d.ID,d.[Date]
;
```